# Why does strtok occasionally cause a bus error?

Tags: c, split, c-strings

EDIT: I have made the info here more specific and executed some recommendations from the comments.

---

I have a shell written in C that works like a charm when used. However, I have some tests written for a function called `pipe_exec` that causes a bus error. I thought it was originally from `strtok` in my `split` function (and it may still be).

The `pipe_exec` func basically deals with commands with pipes like `ls -a | wc -l` or something. It always works fine when I'm using the actual shell but with the tests, there's always a bus error if there are any flags involved with the piped commands.

The issue could jut be with my test.

But I have no clue what the issue is. It's tracing back to the `strtok` in my `split` function, but it only has a bus issue with the tests and never in any actual equivalent situations.

Any help here is appreciated. Sorry for so much code to look at.

`shell_exec_tests.c`

```
static char *args1[20] = {"ls ", " wc"};     // works
static char *args2[20] = {"ls -a", "wc -l"}; // causes bus error

static int a = 0;
static int b = 0;

void test_setup(void)
{   
    a = pipe_exec(args1);
    b = pipe_exec(args2);
}

void test_teardown(void)
{
    // nothing
}

MU_TEST(test_check) 
{
    mu_check(a == EXIT_SUCCESS);
    mu_check(b == EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

MU_TEST_SUITE(test_suite)
{
    MU_SUITE_CONFIGURE(&test_setup, &test_teardown);
    MU_RUN_TEST(test_check);
}

int main() 
{
    MU_RUN_SUITE(test_suite);
    MU_REPORT();
    return MU_EXIT_CODE;
}
```

`pipe_exec.c`

```
// make_proc: determine if a process goes to stdout or takes in data from stdin
void make_proc(int in, int out, char **cmd)
{
    pid_t rc;
    int status;
    rc = fork();
    if (rc < 0) {
        perror("fork");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (rc  == 0) {
        if (in != STDIN_FILENO) {
            dup2(in, STDIN_FILENO);
            close(in);
        }
        if (out != STDOUT_FILENO) {
            dup2(out, STDOUT_FILENO);
            close(out);
        }
        execvp(*cmd, cmd);
        errmsg(*cmd);
        exit(1);
    }
    waitpid(rc, &status, WUNTRACED);
    return;
}


// pipe_exec: loop through each command, connecting each through a pipe
int pipe_exec(char **args)
{
    int in, status, return_val;
    int pipe_no; // keep track of no. of cmds seperated by pipes 
    int pfd[2];
    pid_t rc;
    char **cmd;
    
    return_val = EXIT_SUCCESS;
    in = 0;
    pipe_no = 0;
    while (*args) {
        cmd = split(*args, " \t\r\n");
        if (!args[1]) {
            break;
        }

        if (pipe(pfd) < 0) {
            perror("pipe");
        }

        make_proc(in, pfd[1], cmd);
        close(pfd[1]);
        in = pfd[0];
        args++;
        pipe_no++;
    }
    // move pointer back
    args -= pipe_no;

    rc = fork();
    if (rc < 0) {
        perror("fork");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (rc == 0) {
        if (in != 0) dup2(in, STDIN_FILENO);
        execvp(*cmd, cmd);
        errmsg(*cmd);
        return_val = EXIT_FAILURE;
        exit(1);
    }
    waitpid(rc, &status, WUNTRACED);

    // pretty sure i need a pipe to get the EXIT_FAILURE from
    // the child if the child fails, but for now im just working
    // on finding that bus error issue
    return return_val;
}
```

And lastly, my `split` function:

```
// trim: trim leading and trailing whitespace on a string
static char *trim(char *str)
{
  char *end;

  // Trim leading space
  while(isspace((unsigned char)*str)) str++;

  if(*str == 0)  // All spaces?
    return str;

  // Trim trailing space
  end = str + strlen(str) - 1;
  while(end > str && isspace((unsigned char)*end)) end--;

  // Write new null terminator character
  end[1] = '\0';

  return str;
}


// split: take a string and break it up into an array of strings based on delim
char **split(char *s, const char *delim)
{
    char **split_s;
    char *token;
    size_t len;
    int i;
    
    len = strlen(s);
    
    split_s = calloc(len*2, sizeof(char*));
    if (split_s == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "split: could not allocate memory\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    i = 0;
    token = strtok(s, delim);
    while (token != NULL) {
        split_s[i] = trim(token);
        token = strtok(NULL, delim);
        i++;
    }
    split_s[i] = NULL;
    return split_s;
}
```

Comment: Please show [mcve] including how you call it

Comment: In particular, since `strtok` modifies its input string, a common mistake is to pass it a string literal.  So if you're calling `split("foo,bar,baz", ",")` that could explain it.

Comment: First, `s_len = strlen(*split_s); split_s+=s_len;*split_s = 0;` is useless.  How do you think `strlen()` gets the length of a string?  (It looks for the `NUL` terminator...)  Second, if it did work, `split_s[s_len] = '\0';` would be much better.  Third, `split_s++;` changes the value of `split_s`, which mean you've lost the value returned by `malloc()`.  I hope you never call `free()` on the value returned by your `split()` function because doing so would be undefined behavior and will almost certainly corrupt your heap.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I rewrote my split function function based on your critiques. Although, it didn't fix the problem, I was able to see what I needed to do after. Setting the last element in the newly split array to `NULL` did the trick. Thanks.